# readyState analog for jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

In pure JS:

```
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();
 ...
if (xmlHttp.readyState == 2) {...loading... message...}
if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {...display ajax response...}
```

What is the condition for readyState when using `$ajax()` from jQuery? In other words, what is translated code to jQuery from pure JS above?

Comment: You know you can asign ajax request to a variable, run it on a timer and then use other timed functions to recall the saved ajax variable to make other calls on it. [jQuery .ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

from the link:
No onreadystatechange mechanism is provided, however, since success, error, complete and statusCode cover all conceivable requirements.